# Increase inotify watchers without using root priviledges

Tags: sudo, inotify

Is there a way to increase the amount of inotify watchers without having admin privileges?

In worst case, with apt-get?

I am not admin, but have sudo apt-get install permissions.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? There might be another way around it if you explain the problem that forces you to use too many.

Comment: Basically I would like to run several inode hungry apps: a rails app (even perhaps old version and new to see the diff), browser, few Intellijideas instances

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it without root privileges. The limit is there to make sure no user DoS-es the system. You should ask your system administrator for a higher value.